# How to get page title with the page ID?

Tags: pages, title, id

My page ID is: `30601`.

I want to get the page's title with ID.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
?>
```

get_the_title fetch the title of WordPress post based on particular Id. and get_the_ID() fetch id of that page/post

Comment: Hi, Anurag Tiwari. Thanks for contributing to WP Stack Exchange. Just as a friendly suggestion to make your answers a little bit more compreensive, I encourage you give some context or explanation and/or references to the function in documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Next Time I will do the same